# Fill uneven gap between tile and tub

Tags: tiling

I just finished tiling the shower surround around my tub. I knew that the tub wasn't level when I started but it became more evident toward the end of tiling.

On one end of the tub, there is 1/8" gap between my tub and the tile. On the other end of the tub that gap expands to around 1/4" or more. I checked my tile and it's level all the way around—it's just my tub isn't.

I plan on caulking this gap but are there any special considerations for a gap that large?

Thank you

Comment: Often, folks will start tiling at the ceiling or at some arbitrary level and work downward, then cut tiles to fit against the tub. Is that not the case here?

Comment: I started from the tub and worked up. This was my first shower surround tiling project. It turned out well but now I know why I should pick an arbitrary point and work down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, except that you need a product that doesn't shrink much (or you need to pre-fill to minimize depth and shrinkage). Pure silicone is good, as is urethane (though urethane is *very* difficult to work with if you're inexperienced--it sticks to everything, including fingers, and stays stuck).

1/4" isn't unmanageable. Cut your tube at an angle, then trim the very tip flat:

```
 _
| \
|  \
|   |
|   |
```

Apply the caulk with the cut parallel to the wall, and try to avoid any additional tooling.

Answer (score 0):

Some use a strategy of not caulking that gap at all, to avoid trapping water, rather letting it drain.